# Facebook Messenger opens AppStore instead of browser

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-messenger

I shared a link from the Bright Side (page on FB) to a friend in Facebook Messenger. Then I taped on it and instead of opening it in browser messenger opened AppStore and recommended to download Bright Side app. Is it Bright Side server issue?

Comment: That’s not an “issue”, but a _feature_. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks, http://applinks.org/

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the answer! But, well, to hell such features =_=